# 'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field)

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    
    publishDate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20,default=timezone.now,verbose_name='time')
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField('view', default=0)
   
 


  class Meta:
        verbose_name = 're'
        verbose_name_plural = 're'
        ordering = ('-publishDate',)
```

it says:

> 'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field).

Comment: are you sure this error is not coming from another model? can you add error trace. There is nothing wrong basically in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Just do

ordering = ["-publishDate"]

For more information you can research on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/

Comment: I tried. But it still says，“'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field).”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but it was my code and work well

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField("home.Category", related_name='product')
    name = models.CharField( max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

---

BTW , I recomand to use this way :

```
publishDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='time')
```

'auto_now_add' :  Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created